# JColorChooser- update the range of CMYK

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

I'm using `JColorChooser` for picking a color in Java.

I have been trying to figure out how to change the range of the CMYK from 0-255 to 0-100 (percentage).

In addition, I want to add to the panel color code (like the RGB has).

And in generally, if you have better library that you recommend to use I would like to hear about it.

```java
public class ColorChooser extends JColorChooser {    
        private Color color;

        public ColorChooser(Color currentColor, ColorsPanel cp) {
            setSize(400, 400);
            setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            setColorPanels();
            setPreviewPanel(new JPanel()); // removes the preview panel
            //-12566464 = RGB values for the default color
            if(currentColor.getRGB() != -12566464)
                setColor(currentColor);
            openColorChooser(cp);
        }

        // public

        public void openColorChooser(ColorsPanel cp) {
            JDialog dlg = JColorChooser.createDialog(cp, "", true, this,
                    new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            color = getColor();
                        }
                    }, null);
            dlg.setVisible(true);
        }

        // private

        private void setColorPanels() {
            AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = getChooserPanels();
            for (AbstractColorChooserPanel accp : panels) {
                switch (accp.getDisplayName()) {
                case "HSV":
                    removeChooserPanel(accp);
                    break;
                case "HSL":
                    removeChooserPanel(accp);
                    break;
                case "Swatches":
                    removeChooserPanel(accp);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // getters and setters

        public Color getChosenColor() {
            return color;
        }    
    }
```

[image]

I really need your help!!! I have been trying to solve it a long time ago without success.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you pls add your code, especially only the important once

Comment: currently, i have the basic ui for cmyk, and i want to add the color code, and change the rang to 0-100.. is it possible?  thank you!!

Comment: See [*How to Use Color Choosers: Creating a Custom Chooser Panel*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel).

Comment: thanks for the link, but i already saw it.. i understand that i need to add panel with: addChooserPanel which gets "AbstractColorChooserPanel()" as parameter. but, i don't know how to implement the functions: updateChooser() , getSmallDisplayIcon(), getLargeDisplayIcon(), buildChooser(). i want to get the same panel as mcyk, just to modify the range and add the color code. do you have any sample of how they implementes one of the panels?